# NativeScript Angular + Karma - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angular, nativescript, karma-runner, nativescript-angular, karma-webpack

So I decided to add unit testing to my NS7/NG11 app, followed instructions from NS website and got to the point where the app would start but the screen is blank (all white).

Initialized tests with `ns test init`, manually updated `karma-webpack` in `package.json` to v `5.0.0-alpha.5` as the default one had a bug that was fixed and should be released soon.

Command used to start testing is: `ns test run --emulator`

Testing in `Tabs` template with Angular. When running `ns run ios --emulator` the runs just fine and is usable.

Below is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-tab-navigation-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "displayName": "Tabs",
  "templateType": "App template",
  "version": "7.0.6",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nstudio",
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "template",
    "tab",
    "navigation",
    "category-general"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "@nativescript/unit-test-runner": "^1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "6.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-nativescript-launcher": "0.4.0",
    "karma-webpack": "5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

and here's the console output when I run `ns test ios --emulator`:

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Updating runtime package.json with configuration values...
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Successfully transferred all files on device DF60258A-B86C-4E93-BCEF-4E2ED154E007.
Restarting application on device DF60258A-B86C-4E93-BCEF-4E2ED154E007...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.karmans7 on device DF60258A-B86C-4E93-BCEF-4E2ED154E007.
(RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Identity resolved as application<org.nativescript.karmans7>
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: fetching http://127.0.0.1:9877/context.json
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: fetching http://172.16.1.6:9877/context.json
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: fetching http://172.16.1.4:9877/context.json
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: found karma at 127.0.0.1
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: found karma at 172.16.1.4
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: found karma at 172.16.1.6
CONSOLE LOG: NSUTR: connecting to karma at http://127.0.0.1:9877
CONSOLE LOG: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am encountering the same issue with the out-of-the-box Vue setup.

Comment: After switching to a newer version of Node (14.15.4) and updating NativeScript, I now get `JS: ReferenceError: window is not defined` instead of `CONSOLE LOG: ReferenceError: window is not defined`. So not much progress.

Comment: I reached out to the NS team on Twitter and they said this is a known issue. "We were planning a number of test runner updates to coincide with the planned 8.0 release but will see what we can do to deliver something in the interim here."

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with NativeScript and Karma. They recommend using
`"karma": "5.2.3",` in the meantime.

This also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript does not have a `window` object like a browser does.   So any code that needs to pretend it is running in a browser, you basically need to add a global window object.

At the very top of your app.ts (or main.ts) depending on the NS flavor; add the line:

`global.window = {};` or `global.window = global`
(If you are using TS, you will have to do `(<any>global).` otherwise TypeScript will probably complain about global not being the correct type...

and that should fix the issue.